# How to display an activity automatically

Tags: android

In my application I have created a splash screen type of thing in android. It should remain for 5 seconds. My problem is that how I display another activity automatically after 5 secs? The splash screen doesn't have a button, rather it should display another activity automatically after 5 seconds without the click of the button.
i got this code from stackoverflow but as i am a beginner i dont know where to add this code can anyone please tell me.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            LaunchActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            LaunchActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: Add it in the onCreate of your launchactivity

Comment: Also, don't delay the app for 5 seconds, users hate waiting, especially if nothing is happening

Comment: Sure. Use a splash screen only if effectively needed to mask something loading.

Comment: Add it to your onCreate or onStart method. Assuming the "LaunchActivity" is the Splash screen change the names from "LaunchActivity" to the name of your splash screen activity.. And "HomeActivity" to the activity class you want to land next.

Comment: ok i will surely remember this.

Comment: Ok, edited my comment above to make it work for you.